# Can we get close event of local notification or can we get any midnight date change event?

Tags: iphone

I need to schedule local notification on receiving previously scheduling local notification. I have schedule another notification on close event of local notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't handle the close button event in `UILocalNotification` alert.